# How to use two for loops to randomly replace multiple words in a sentence

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, random

My assignment was to create a random compliment generator that uses two for loops to randomly select and replace both a noun and an adjective in a sentence. I am supposed to utilize the random.choice function to select the noun/adj and then print out the sentence with the replacements. I've done most of it below but for some reason, the program is only replacing the noun but not the adjective. Instead, it's printing out the intended adjective after the placeholder.

```
import random

sentence = "Hi, your *noun is looking *adj today."
sentence = sentence.split()

nouns = ["son", "daughter", "dog", "house"]
adjectives = ["beautiful", "handsome", "pretty", "warm", "fantastic"]

indexCount = 0
for word in sentence:
    if word == "*noun":
        wordChoice = random.choice(nouns)
        sentence[indexCount] = wordChoice
    indexCount += 1

    if word == "*adj":
        wordChoice = random.choice(adjectives)
        sentence[indexCount] = wordChoice

st = ""
for word in sentence:
    st += word + " "
print(st)
```

The output I keep getting in IDLE is similar to:

```
 Hi, your son is looking *adj warm
```

The today isn't printed out at all. When I try to add a second indexCount += 1, the program returns that it's out of range.

Comment: This is a good time to use `enumerate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing *before* you make the check for an adjective, which means where you do the substitution you essentially are getting:

```
if word == "*adj":
    wordChoice = random.choice(adjectives)
    sentence[(indexCount+1)] = wordChoice
```

This explains why the word one *after* "*adj" is getting modified. Instead move the increment of `indexCount` *after* the check for an adjective.

Better is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indexing:

```
for idx, word in enumerate(sentence):
    if word == "*noun":
        wordChoice = random.choice(nouns)
        sentence[idx] = wordChoice

    if word == "*adj":
        wordChoice = random.choice(adjectives)
        sentence[idx] = wordChoice
```

Also when building your results you might as well use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
st = " ".join(sentence)
```

Comment: Wow! enumerate was something that I wasn't taught at all. It's so convenient to not manually set the indexCount to 0. I'll try this solution out and get back to you.

Comment: I tried the enumerate method, but I keep getting an error that on the line that says sentence[idx] = wordChoice. It says that wordChoice is not defined.

Comment: @Dev ah yes this was a bug, should be fixed now

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works perfectly now. Now I have to understand it completely and be able to use it in my practical tomorrow. Thanks for the helpful tips on enumerate and join, they'll save me a lot of time.

Comment: @Dev Glad to help! If this question has been helpful you can mark it as the accepted answer by checking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go simpler:

```
import random
nouns = ["son", "daughter", "dog", "house"]
adjectives = ["beautiful", "handsome", "pretty", "warm", "fantastic"]
```

Now a simple print statement, while long, is super easy to use:

```
print "Hi, your", random.choice(nouns), "is looking", random.choice(adjectives), "today."
Hi, your dog is looking beautiful today.
```

Comment: Whoops - I didn't get the requirement for the for loops first.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! If I wasn't mandated to use for loops this is probably what I would've gone with. It's really simple, however, it doesn't satisfy the requirements.